# How to setup angular12 with eslint in VS2019?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, eslint

I have `angular(12)` project in VS2019 with TSLint.

I have migrated project from tslint to eslint with following commands.

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics

ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint
```

It will generate `.eslintrc.json` file with the default rules.

I have enable ESLint as below:
[image]

Here its referencing to global configuration file.
I want to change this to generated .eslintrc.json file.

I want Linting as per .eslintrc.json file. How to achieve this in VS 2019?

Comment: Have you find any solution? I tried same and visual studio gives "(ESLint) Fatal-Error ESLint encountered a parsing error."

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, I haven't found a solution yet.